# Getting memory leak after keeping IE11 open for 2 days

Tags: typescript, memory, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-11, angular6

Recently I found there is a memory leak in IE11 for angular6 application where i have several's tabs in application and each tab is having multiple graphs to show.

There is no memory leak for sudden open and close the application but if I allowed to open a browser for 2 days with active tab open, i saw a memory spike where memory aren't being released properly and memory allocation is getting upward after that and its repeating the same pattern over the time.

Is there any way to find out which script is issuing the memory leak? Because this pattern is only getting after 2 days so that i cannot keep profiling open for 2 days.

Please let me know if any other work around to find out like using perfmon, selenium or node js to keep checking memory consumption and if there is any spike, take a snapshot.

Below is the sanpshot.

[image]

Comment: Is you app doing some kind of polling?

Comment: Yes..every 5sec

Comment: if there are  console.log statements when you get the data, you need to remove them especially when they log objects.

Comment: Using console how would you figure out memory leak..

Comment: Pramod : Are there console logs?

Comment: No there is no console logs as such