# Set up and Configuration of Sampling Heap Profiler node module

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, angular6, heap-memory

I am getting very hard time to configure Sampling Heap Profiler node module.

I would like to set up this module and want to try deploying in chrome dev tool but unfortunately, there is no document about build and deployment.

Here is the npm link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/heap-profile

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The sampling heap profiler is designed to be used programmatically in Node.js applications.

For frontend applications, you actually don't need this module. The functionality is baked into DevTools. You can find the 'Allocation Sampling' profiler in the 'Memory' tab in Chrome Devtools:

[image: DevTools allocation sampling]

Comment: Thanks for taking this question!! Can i use this option and record the sampling for continuous 2 days without closing the browser. I ve certain task that  need to be monitored upto 2 weeks. Here is the more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52552587/getting-memory-leak-after-keeping-ie11-open-for-2-days)

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. The sampling based heap profiler in V8 is designed to be used continuously in production (typically on the server side). While I haven't tested this in a browser, I expect it work there too.